# При уменьшении размера экрана сдвигается содержимое

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, content

Всем привет. Верстаю с bootstrap. При уменьшении экрана, блок с формой и контактами почему то уезжает вправо и скрывается.. Что нужно сделать чтобы не уезжал?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
#second {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  height: 653px;
  width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.second_content_center {
  margin-top: -88px;
  padding: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 650px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.form_contacts_left h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form_contacts_left span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.form_contacts_left_email_icon {
  margin-right: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 47px;
}

.form_contacts_left_phones_icon {
  margin-right: 33px;
  margin-bottom: 47px;
}

.form_contacts_left_skype_icon {
  margin-right: 26px;
}

.form_contacts {
  background: #11b2f5;
  width: 400px;
  height: 468px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 53px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.form_heading_contacts {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form_text_contacts {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form_input_contacts {
  width: 90%;
  height: 53px;
  background: #30c2ff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.form_btn_contacts {
  width: 90%;
  height: 55px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 9px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form_contacts_left {
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.form_input_contacts::placeholder {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 300px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b5e5ff;
}

.form_input_contacts:hover::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="second">
  <div class="second_content_center">
    <h3 class="form_contacts_heading text-center">Мы всегда на связи и ответим на все интересующие Вас вопросы!</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-sm-5">
          <div class="form_contacts_left">
            <div class="form_contacts_left_phones d-flex">
              <div class="form_contacts_left_phones_icon">
                <img src="img/phones.png" alt="phones">
              </div>
              <div class="form_contacts_left_phones_text">
                <h4>Телефоны</h4>
                <span>В Болгарии  8 (123) 12-123-123</span><br>
                <span>В России     8 (495) 12-123-123</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form_contacts_left_email d-flex">
              <div class="form_contacts_left_email_icon">
                <img src="img/email.png" alt="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form_contacts_left_email_text">
                <h4>E-MAIL</h4>
                <span>info@sitename.ru</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form_contacts_left_skype d-flex">
              <div class="form_contacts_left_skype_icon">
                <img src="img/skype.png" alt="skype">
              </div>
              <div class="form_contacts_left_skype_text">
                <h4>Skype</h4>
                <span>skypename</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 ml-auto text-center">
          <div class="form_contacts">
            <h2 class="form_heading_contacts"><span>Есть вопросы</span><br> по переезду в болгарию?</h2>
            <p class="form_text_contacts">Мы проконсультируем<br> Вас бесплатно!</p>
            <form action="#">
              <input class="form_input_contacts" type="text" placeholder="Имя"><br>
              <input class="form_input_contacts" type="email" placeholder="E_MAIL"><br>
              <input class="form_input_contacts" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон"><br>
              <button class="form_btn_contacts">Заказать консультацию</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У блока `second` установленна фиксированая ширина, точно так же как и у блока с формой `form_contacts`. Можно заменить свойство `width` для блока `form_contacts` на `max-width`, что бы он подстраивался под размер родителя. У блока `second` можно вообще убрать свойство `width` так как бутсраповский класс `container` уже имеет свойство `max-width` которое ограничивает его размер.

```css
#second {
  background: #f7f7f7;
  height: 653px;
  max-width: 1040px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 7px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
}

.second_content_center {
  margin-top: -88px;
  padding: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  height: 650px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.form_contacts_left h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form_contacts_left span {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.form_contacts_left_email_icon {
  margin-right: 26px;
  margin-bottom: 47px;
}

.form_contacts_left_phones_icon {
  margin-right: 33px;
  margin-bottom: 47px;
}

.form_contacts_left_skype_icon {
  margin-right: 26px;
}

.form_contacts {
  background: #11b2f5;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 468px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-top: 53px;
  padding: 1px;
}

.form_heading_contacts {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form_text_contacts {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.form_input_contacts {
  width: 90%;
  height: 53px;
  background: #30c2ff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.form_btn_contacts {
  width: 90%;
  height: 55px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 9px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form_contacts_left {
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.form_input_contacts::placeholder {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 300px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #b5e5ff;
}

.form_input_contacts:hover::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<section id="second">
  <div class="second_content_center">
    <h3 class="form_contacts_heading text-center">Мы всегда на связи и ответим на все интересующие Вас вопросы!</h3>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-sm-5">
          <div class="form_contacts_left">
            <div class="form_contacts_left_phones d-flex">
              <div class="form_contacts_left_phones_icon">
                <img src="img/phones.png" alt="phones">
              </div>
              <div class="form_contacts_left_phones_text">
                <h4>Телефоны</h4>
                <span>В Болгарии  8 (123) 12-123-123</span><br>
                <span>В России     8 (495) 12-123-123</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form_contacts_left_email d-flex">
              <div class="form_contacts_left_email_icon">
                <img src="img/email.png" alt="email">
              </div>
              <div class="form_contacts_left_email_text">
                <h4>E-MAIL</h4>
                <span>info@sitename.ru</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form_contacts_left_skype d-flex">
              <div class="form_contacts_left_skype_icon">
                <img src="img/skype.png" alt="skype">
              </div>
              <div class="form_contacts_left_skype_text">
                <h4>Skype</h4>
                <span>skypename</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-5 col-xl-5 col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 ml-auto text-center">
          <div class="form_contacts">
            <h2 class="form_heading_contacts"><span>Есть вопросы</span><br> по переезду в болгарию?</h2>
            <p class="form_text_contacts">Мы проконсультируем<br> Вас бесплатно!</p>
            <form action="#">
              <input class="form_input_contacts" type="text" placeholder="Имя"><br>
              <input class="form_input_contacts" type="email" placeholder="E_MAIL"><br>
              <input class="form_input_contacts" type="tel" placeholder="Телефон"><br>
              <button class="form_btn_contacts">Заказать консультацию</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Убрать длину у #second Не получилось, так как у .second_content_center разные фоны и .second_content_center имеет отрицательный margin-top. Если убрать вообще длину, то .second_content_center растягивается на всю длину, а это мне не нужно. Помогло max-width для #second. Теперь все идеально адаптируется. Спасибо большое.